# compare 2 arrays and leave

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, higher-order-functions

```
var arr1 = [11, 12, 13];
var arr2 = [
      { id: 11, name: "name 1" },
      { id: 12, name: "name 2" },
      { id: 13, name: "name 3" },
      { id: 14, name: "name 4" },
];
```

I have this two arrays and in the second array want to leave items which id's equal to first array values. I mean this:

```
  var newArray = [
          { id: 11, name: "name 1" },
          { id: 12, name: "name 2" },
          { id: 13, name: "name 3" },
    ];
```

What is most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `arr2.filter(item => arr1.includes(item.id))`

Comment: @JaredFarrish I tried this but it isn't filtering. Is it happening because arr1 items aren't number and arr2 id's are numbers?

Comment: Converted all items into Numbers and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @tako-sphynx I added an answer demonstrating it working with what was given. I see you also got it working elsewhere with a cast.

Comment: That's a very awkward title.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple filter accessing the item `id` and checking if that `id` is included in the first array.

```js
var arr1 = [11, 12, 13];
var arr2 = [
      { id: 11, name: "name 1" },
      { id: 12, name: "name 2" },
      { id: 13, name: "name 3" },
      { id: 14, name: "name 4" },
];
var newArray = arr2.filter(item => arr1.includes(item.id));

console.log(newArray);
```

Edit: In the spirit of efficient execution, another approach:

```js
var arr1 = [11, 12, 13];
var arr2 = [
      { id: 11, name: "name 1" },
      { id: 12, name: "name 2" },
      { id: 13, name: "name 3" },
      { id: 14, name: "name 4" },
];
var objIds = arr1.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item] = true) && obj, {})
var newArray = arr2.filter(item => objIds[item.id]);

console.log(objIds, newArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, build an *index* by mapping each id to its corresponding object.  The index object will have this structure:

```
{
  '11': { id: 11, name: 'name 1' },
  '12': { id: 12, name: 'name 2' },
  '13': { id: 13, name: 'name 3' },
  '14': { id: 14, name: 'name 4' }
}
```

This index can be built in a variety of ways, one of which is to use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).  `Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]))`.

Then map each `id` in your `arr1` to its corresponding object with a lookup in your `index` object: `index[id]`.  That will look like `arr1.map(id => index[id])`.

```js
var arr1 = [11, 12, 13];
var arr2 = [
      { id: 11, name: "name 1" },
      { id: 12, name: "name 2" },
      { id: 13, name: "name 3" },
      { id: 14, name: "name 4" },
];

const index = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
const result = arr1.map(id => index[id]);
console.log(result);
```

This approach is efficient because it does not perform a linear search for each item's index (no `.includes` or `.find` per entry is required).  Instead, it leverages the hashtable lookup of a property in an object (which is more or less constant time).  Overall this is O(N) instead of O(N^2).

Beware, there may more overhead in creating such an index for small values of N.  But for larger values of N this will be better, and also will be better if there are multiple variations of `arr1` objects to be used with a single `arr2`.